# How can I parallelize data collection for Reinforcement Learning with tf-agents?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, reinforcement-learning, agent

I am training a Reinforcement Learning model with tf-agents for the Cartpole environment.

I use the code from github:
[Code on Github](https://github.com/tensorflow/agents/blob/master/docs/tutorials/9_c51_tutorial.ipynb)

To speed up the data collection process, I want to parallelize it and run it on multiple cores of my CPU. Can anyone give me tips on how to do this with tf-agents? What approach should I choose for this?